# What is the probability of the product rolled with 4 different dice being 24?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Four ways to roll 24:

- 1 1 4 6
- 1 2 2 6
- 1 2 3 4
- <del>2 2 3 4</del> 2 2 2 3

Since the dice are different, there are 4! ways to arrange each way, so $\frac{4*4!}{6^4} = \frac{2}{27}$?

Comment: 2, 2, 3, 4 gives a product of 48 btw.

Comment: @Iwanttomakegames Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

First of all, the only ways to roll a 24 product are: $1, 1, 4, 6$ and $1, 2, 2, 6$ and $2, 2, 2, 3$ and $1, 2, 3, 4$.

Second thing - there are not 4! ways to arrange for example $1,1,4,6$ or $1,2,2,6$. There are only $12$ ways to do so (you have to pick a place for two numbers and then the remaining spots get filled in).

Similarly there are only $4$ ways of arranging $2, 2, 2, 3$.

Comment: So is the final answer $\frac{4+12+12+24}{6^4}$?

Comment: Yes, it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "ways to arrange" must take into account the undistinguishable outcomes

To count them, say you have $n$ objects, divided into $k$ disjoint classes of undistinguishable objects, and say that class $C_i$ ($0≤i<k$) has size $m_i$, where $\sum_{i<k} m_i = n$, the number of different arrangements is
$$
\frac{n!}{\prod m_i!}
$$

When all objects are distinct, this is the same as $n!$, but in the case that you have two equal objects, the result is $\frac{n!}{2}$.

Also you forget $(2,2,2,3)$, which has $\frac{4!}{3!} = 4$ ways to arrange.